# Material-UI Menu Height Issue

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, menu-items

I want to set the menu height equal to window height by applying css. If the elements in the page increases vertically then with respect to the page length, the menu-height should also be increasing. I have used "height:100%" & also tried using "height: 100vh" in the styles but it's not working.

**Any help??**

I have the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Menu from 'material-ui/Menu';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import './mystyle.css';

const mainmenu = {
 width: '180px',
 height: '100%',
};

class MenuView extends Component {
 render() {
  return (
    <div className="dash-menuview">
       <Menu style={mainmenu} className="mydashboard">
         <MenuItem primaryText="My Name" style={{color:'white'}} href="#/name" onClick={handlers.changeURL}/>
         <MenuItem primaryText="Personal Information" style={{color:'white'}} href="#/information" onClick={handlers.changeURL}/>
         <MenuItem primaryText="My Address" style={{color:'white'}} href="#/current" onClick={handlers.changeURL}/>
         <MenuItem primaryText="My Files" style={{color:'white'}} href="#/files" onClick={handlers.logout}/>  
       </Menu>
    </div>
  );
 }
}
export default MenuView;
```

**mystyle.css**

```
.dash-menuview {
   margin-left: -8.8%;
}
.mydashboard {
  background: #545454;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 0%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `height:100%` with `height:30` and also assign same height to `lineHeight:30`

Comment: It's not working.. read the question carefully.. I want the menu-height to increase automatically whenever the elements in the page increases vertically. As an example, suppose I click on 'Personal Information' and the elements in the page increases and the scroll-bar comes then the menu-height should also be increasing automatically with respect to the window. That's all..

Comment: Please provide more information as picture of what you are currently having and what output you want. Also try to add jsfiddle or codepen.

Answer (score 0):

In order to override height styling, you need to use classes api. please refer to [link](https://v3.material-ui.com/customization/overrides/#overriding-with-classes) for further specs.
In my personal use and also from the code example from Material ui doc, here's some revised example from your code. I used withStyles, and classes to override styling and changed className dash-menuview to dashMenuview (for easier assignment). Hope it helps.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
    import Menu from 'material-ui/Menu';
    import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
    import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
    
    const styles = {
      dashMenuview {
        margin-left: -8.8%,
      },
      mydashboard {
        background: #545454,
        color: #FFFFFF,
        text-decoration: none,
        color: white,
        margin-left: 0%,
        font-weight: bold,
      },
    };
    
    class MenuView extends Component {
         constructor(props){}
         render() {
          { classes } = this.props

            return (
                <div classes={{root: classes.dashMenuview}}>
                   <Menu style={mainmenu} classes={{root: classes.mydashboard}}>
                     <MenuItem primaryText="My Name" style={{color:'white'}} href="#/name" onClick={handlers.changeURL}/>
                     <MenuItem primaryText="Personal Information" style={{color:'white'}} href="#/information" onClick={handlers.changeURL}/>
                     <MenuItem primaryText="My Address" style={{color:'white'}} href="#/current" onClick={handlers.changeURL}/>
                     <MenuItem primaryText="My Files" style={{color:'white'}} href="#/files" onClick={handlers.logout}/>  
                 </Menu>
               </div>
      );
 }
}
    
    ClassesNesting.propTypes = {
      classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    };
    
    export default withStyles(styles)(ClassesNesting);
```